# Primitive element in $L^H:=\{\alpha\in L:\thinspace \sigma\alpha=\alpha\thinspace$ $\forall\sigma\in H\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm studying Galois theory and I'm stuck in the following problem.

Let $L=K(x)$ the field of rational expresions over a field $K$ with $char(K)=p>0$. Let $\sigma\in Aut(L/K)$ the automorphism determinated by $\sigma(x)=x+1$. Show that $H:=\langle\sigma\rangle$ is a finite subgroup of $G=Aut(L/K)$, and find $\alpha\in L^H$ such that $L^G=K(\alpha)$.

For the first part, I need to write explicitly what is H?.

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: You can try to calculate powers of $\sigma$. Since $\sigma$ is the identity on $K$, it suffices to calculate $\sigma^i(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Compute $\sigma(x)=x+1$, $\sigma^2(x)=\sigma(\sigma(x)) = \sigma(x+1) =\sigma(x)+\sigma(1)=(x+1)+1=x+2$.
Then $\sigma^k(x)=x+k$ for $k\geq 0$.
Thus $\sigma^p(x)=x$ and $\sigma^p$ is the identity.
Hence, $H=\{id, \sigma,\ldots,\sigma^{p-1}\}$.